# Problems with RMI, callback registering failed

Tags: java, rmi

i'm in trouble about a problem with RMI. I'm trying to set up a client-server but it seems that the client doesn't "know" the server.

As you can see with this code :

```
public class ChatClient {


static String t;
static ReceiveCallback callback;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, NotBoundException
{
     callback = new Afficheur();

    ChatRemote chat = (ChatRemote) Naming.lookup("//localhost/chat");


    chat.registerCallback(callback);

    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while(!(t = read.readLine()).equals("fin"))
    {
        chat.send("myName",t);
    }
}

}
```

This returns me errors below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tp.rmi.serveur.ChatRemoteImpl.registerCallback(ChatRemoteImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
at $Proxy0.registerCallback(Unknown Source)
at tp.rmi.client.ChatClient.main(ChatClient.java:26)
```

I'm using a ChatRemote interface :

```
public interface ChatRemote extends Remote{

public String echo(String name, String message) throws RemoteException;
public void send(String name, String message) throws RemoteException;
public void registerCallback(ReceiveCallback callback) throws RemoteException;
```

}

and my server class looks like this

```
public class ChatServeur {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {



    ChatRemote chat = new ChatRemoteImpl();
    Naming.rebind("///chat", chat);
    System.out.println(chat+" enregistré");

}
    }
```

To finish, i'm running a script rmiregistry.sh in background. I have some arguments for both classes (Server and Client) :

Server :

```
-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=chat.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/private/student/7/17/10003117/workspace/TP3_MRI/bin/ -Djava.rmi.server.hostname="localhost"
```

Client :`-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=chat.policy`

A git repo is available here https://bitbucket.org/t3x4s/mri/src if you want to check my whole code

Thanks for answers
T

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tp.rmi.serveur.ChatRemoteImpl.registerCallback(ChatRemoteImpl.java:43)
```

You are dereferencing a null pointer at line 43 of ChatRemoteImpl.java.

Why you posted this question without the relevant code is a mystery to me. In any case you are expected to be able to sort out your own NPEs. At least I expect it.